# Solidity multiple vs single require

Tags: solidity, contract-development, testing, require

One of the functions of my smart contract can only be executed if three conditions are met. At the moment I have a single `require` which combines all the conditions like this:

```
  require(evalCond1() && evalCond2() && evalCond3());
```

But when I try to check my code coverage with `solidity-coverage` it only sees two branches: the one in which the `require` is met and the other, in which at least one of those conditions evaluates to false (no matter which one). I was wondering if there was any issue with breaking down the single `require` in three separate ones, one for each condition:

```
 require(evalCond1());
 require(evalCond2());
 require(evalCond3());
```

I think this improves readability (since the real function names are a bit more complex than `evalCond`) and helps showing the correct coverage for branches, but I'm not sure this doesn't have any side effects regarding gas usage and performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comparing the bytecode generated by each approach, the second is 6 bytes longer - basically because the `REVERT` opcode and associate memory stuff appears 3 times instead of once. But since these instructions are not executed (unless something goes wrong!) this is irrelevant. Both approaches result in the same number of `JUMPI`s

In short, the gas usage will be near enough the same with either approach within half a dozen gas, so take your pick.